# Where do I find game modes and how do I start games in them?

Tags: garrys-mod

I'm really new to Garry's mod and I've been hearing a lot about different gameplay modes in Garry's mod. Are these built into the game? If not, where can I get them? How do I create a game with a game mode running?

Answer (score 1):

The absolute best place to find SWEPS, Models, Maps, Tools, and Game Modes is [garrysmod.org](http://www.garrysmod.org/downloads/).

Comment: Adding to Weegee's answer you can also join a multiplayer game with a gamemode once you join the server you have the gamemode ;)

Comment: Could use some more explanation on where to implement it and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

To get a gamemode a decent place to go is the Steam Workshop due to the one-click installs and uninstalls. To play a gamemode in singleplayer (or if you port forward, online multiplayer) go to SINGLEPLAYER, select the number of players and the map, then in the bottom right corner there is a box saying "SANDBOX". Click it and select the gamemode you installed.

If you want to play on a server that has a gamemode, just join. Gamemode files will be downloaded to your computer along with any custom content they have. Please note that once you join a server, you will not need to redownload their content. If they have addons that other servers have, you will not have to download these addons on those servers.